# Code Generation using CasADi and IPOPT in Simulink for MPC Problem

Tags: code-generation, simulink, ipopt, casadi

I am trying to generate code in Simulink using level 2 S-Function. I am able to generate code in Simulink but the problem is Simulink is not recognizing the IPOPT. It is using its own solvers to solve the problem.
Please share your experiences here, it will help a lot.

I am using CasADi with IPOPT and I have tried level 2 S-Function in Simulink.